# Overload operator[] with different return Type

Tags: c++, json, sfinae, c++98, enable-if

I am working on JSON format using <C++98> and for that reason, I have defined 3 classes :

```
class Json {
public:
    string key;
};
```

```
class JsonElement:public Json {
public:
    string value;
}
```

```
class JsonObject: public Json {
public:
    std::vector<Json*> elements;
```

I neglected the *JsonList* for the moment.

I overloaded the  `operator[]` so that if the operator finds another `JsonObject`, it will call the  `operator[]` once again until it finds `JsonElement` and here it returns the value and not a `Json`

I don't know if I can use  `enable_if` to achieve that or maybe you have another solution.

the idea is this : (this is not a code just the idea)

```
Json || string operator[](const char* key){
     
     if(this->getElementByKey(key) is JsonObject)
         return Json;
     else if(this->getElementByKey(key) is JsonElement)) 
         return this->getElementByKey(key)->value;
}
```

in that way we can use for example :

```
JsonObject jObj;

string value = jObj["key1"]["key2"]
```

Comment: The return type of a function has to be known at compile time. You're not going to be able to write something that maybe returns a `Json` and maybe returns a `string` depending on the actual value of the argument passed to it.

Comment: Even in C++98 (yikes) you shouldn't need to use `this->`.

Comment: You have to pick *one* and only one return type. C++98 is going to say "Deal with it". C++17 says ["I got you"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @NathanPierson, I know that and  that's why I'm tending to overload the operator  ``` operator[]``` with ````enable_if````

Comment: Why not get a JSON parser?  Or look to see how other C++-based JSON parsers handle this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not sure they work with 20th century technology.

Comment: Your `Json` might have `operator std::string` for the final conversion.

Comment: @Gismail And what I'm telling you is that `enable_if` is a compile-time tool and fundamentally you're going to have to be performing this "overload resolution" at runtime. If my JSON looks like `{"Key1": {"NestedKey": "NestedValue"}, "Key2": "FlatValue"}`, there's no way to tell _at compile time_ whether the `string` version of `operator[]` or the `JSON` version of `operator[]` should be called, because `"Key1"` and `"Key2"` are both the same type.

Comment: @NathanPierson, I have seen the ArduinoJsonProject using this [link](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) so, I am wondering if it is possible to do something similar.

Comment: I am not saying that one function should return differents type, but maybe with different functions and different conditions we make the compiler choose the right function.

Comment: Well, I don't know how Arduino JSON does it, but from the example I would suspect its JSON type has conversion operators like Jarod suggested, where the fact that you're assigning `doc["sensor"]` to a `const char*` means that it converts the return value, rather than actually returning something different from `operator[]`.